# Select complex object by join - error: Expression of type '' cannot be used for parameter of type "

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, automapper

I have to select complex DTO from database that looks like this:

```
public class ClientAppointmentCabinetDto : ClientAppointmentDto
{
    public string SpecialistName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ResultProcedureDto> Procedures { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ClientCashIncomeDto> CashIncome { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DocumentDto> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Here ClientAppointmentDto is Dto with simple properties and few user types, which I am not using in this query below.

My efforts were ended up on this solution:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ClientAppointmentCabinetDto>> GetCabinetInfo(int clientId)
    {
        var appointmentIds = DbContext.ClientAppointments.Where(a => a.ClientId == clientId).Select(a => a.Id).ToList();
        var cashSet = DbContext.ClientCashIncome.Where(c => c.ClientId == clientId);
        var cashDtos = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ClientCashIncomeDto>>(cashSet);
        var procedureQuery = DbContext.ClientAppointmentResultProcedures.Where(p => appointmentIds.Contains(p.ClientAppointmentResultId ?? -2));
        var procedureDtos = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ResultProcedureDto>>(procedureQuery);

        var result = await (from apps in DbContext.ClientAppointments
                      join cash in cashDtos on apps.ClientId equals cash.ClientId into cashes
                      join proc in procedureDtos on apps.Id equals (int)proc.AppointmentId into procedures
                      from spec in DbContext.Specialists.Where(s => s.Id == apps.SpecialistId)
                      from branch in DbContext.Branches.Where(b => b.Id == apps.BranchId)
                      where apps.ClientId == clientId
                      select new ClientAppointmentCabinetDto
                      {
                          Id = apps.Id,
                          SpecialistName = spec.Name,
                          StartDate = apps.StartDate,
                          EndDate = apps.EndDate,
                          BranchName = branch.Name,
                          Procedures = procedures,
                          CashIncome = cashes
                      }).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }
```

Looks well, but I'm getting an error while fetching result variable:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'Result' on 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ClientAppointment.ClientAppointmentCabinetDto]]'.
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ResultProcedure.ResultProcedureDto]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ResultProcedure.ResultProcedureDto]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ResultProcedure.ResultProcedureDto] Where[ResultProcedureDto](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ResultProcedure.ResultProcedureDto], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ResultProcedure.ResultProcedureDto,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg0'))
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ResultProcedure.ResultProcedureDto]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ResultProcedure.ResultProcedureDto]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ResultProcedure.ResultProcedureDto] Where[ResultProcedureDto](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ResultProcedure.ResultProcedureDto], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ResultProcedure.ResultProcedureDto,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg0')
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(MethodInfo method, Expression arg0, Expression arg1)
...
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred in the system: Error getting value from 'Result' on 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LAPICore.Domain.DTO.ClientAppointment.ClientAppointmentCabinetDto]]'. See additional information in the logs
   at LAPICore.Api.Middlewares.LogCurrentHttpContextDataMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\Tropin Alexey\Source\Repos\l2api\v2\LAPICore.Api\Middlewares\LogCurrentHttpContextDataMiddleware.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Joining to in-memory collections (like your `cashDtos` and `procedureDto`) is not supported.

Comment: You have to work with `IQueryable` and do not mix `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`. Your mapper should return IQueryable variant if you need effective LINQ query.

Comment: I tried to select DTOs `.AsQueriable()` but got error: `System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression DbSet<ClientAppointment>.GroupJoin(outer: EnumerableQuery<ClientCashIncomeDto> { }, inner: apps => apps.ClientId,        outerKeySelector: cash => cash.ClientId, innerKeySelector: (apps, cashes) => new { apps = apps, cashes = cashes })' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.`

Comment: @IvanStoev What would you do in my situation?

Comment: @TropinAlexey, problem in your mapper. Try to write code without mapper and then you can continue complicating your life. I don't know which mapper do  you use, but maybe it supports that `_mapper.Map<IQueryable<ResultProcedureDto>>(procedureQuery)`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, everything will work if map Dto to List:

```
var cashDtos = _mapper.Map<List<ClientCashIncomeDto>>(cashSet);
```

At least Automapper does that easily. Then, you can use `cashDtos` results in EF queries